# Excel cell list showing as string in Python

Tags: python, excel, label, jira-rest-api

I have a excel table, in which I have a column as below. Which is label list from JIRA

[image]

I would like to take each cell value as a list by running a for loop. For example:

List=['[Engineering]','[Non-Engineering]']

Then I will use it to update my JIRA issue label by following

issue.update(fields={'labels': List})

However loop in python take this as string only as below.

[image]

How can I have this cell value as a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the unneeded character from the string, and then split it by the delimiter.

**Example:**

```
label = "['[Engineering]','[Non-Engineering]']"


label = label[1:]
label = label[:-1]
label = label.replace("'","")

label_list = label.split(',')
```

**Output**

```
>>> label_list
['[Engineering]', '[Non-Engineering]']
```

Do this in the for loop and save the lists in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I need keep the bracket. That means the output I require
['[Engineering]','[Non-Engineering]']

Comment: Adopted it to only remove the outer brackets